# MySQL order by DATETIME field outputting wrong posts order

Tags: php, mysqli, unix-timestamp

I’m trying to order my posts by MySQL datetime field
So I’m instating data in following format

```
gmdate('Y-m-d h:i:s');
```

Below my query

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_stats = 1 ORDER BY published_date DESC LIMIT 10
```

And the posts order is wrong. Then I tried

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_stats = 1 ORDER BY DATE(published_date) DESC LIMIT 10
```

Also tried

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_stats = 1 ORDER BY UNIXDATE(published_date) DESC LIMIT 10
```

Still the posts order is wrong.

EDIT

Ex

my posts should be displayed as

```
post 2 | 2016-12-20 04:52:08
post 1 | 2016-12-20 04:51:20
```

but it is displaying as

```
post 1 | 2016-12-20 04:51:20
post 2 | 2016-12-20 04:52:08
```

Can someone point me out what I’m doing wrong here? Appreciate your time.

Comment: what are your results? what are your expected results?

Comment: @mistermartin simply want it to order by DATETIME stamp but it is displaying a wrong order.

Comment: that doesn't answer my questions. i cannot assume what the wrong or correct order is, unless you show me.

Comment: @mistermartin just added a example.please check. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

a tips how i do so things go with time do a ai in ur database called id and allways order by id :D

Comment: i don't want to order by id. because posts will be inactive till it is published. so i want to order by published date.and time DESC

Comment: set a id when it publish is one way to do it?

Comment: as far as i know you cannot insert a auto increment id manually

Comment: you can with php if u just run throw the database and go for the id2 and then incres for every published then u can set that number in the id2 of the post u publish

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the `DESC` is your issue. Try `ASC` like

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
WHERE post_stats = 1 
ORDER BY published_date ASC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Well seems that changing my date format from 12 hours to 24 hours seems to do the trick

```
gmdate('Y-m-d h:i:s');
```

to

```
gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```